# How can I add complex WGN to a complex damped signal for a specified SNR?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, noise, snr, complex-random-variable

I want to add complex wgn to a signal for a specified SNR.  I have been using the following lines:

```
SNR = -10:5:50;
for l = 1:length(SNR)
   SignalN = awgn(Signal, SNR(l),'measured','dB');
end
```

where $Signal$ is the actual complex damped signal and the $SNR$ is in dB.  I want to replace the above line with $randn$ function in MATLAB that considers the definition of WGN and SNR in dB.  can someone help me with this?

Comment: just type `edit awgn.m` and you access to the source code of the `awgn()` function.

Comment: Do you want to noise to be complex as well ?

Comment: Thank you AlexTP.  I do not want to continue using awgn, instead I want to use randn function that fulfils the same requirement as awgn.

Comment: Hi Hilmar.  Yes I want it to be complex WGN, but without using the awgn or wgn functions from MATLAB.  I want it to be with randn function in MATLAB

Comment: @Neuling well, if you ever look at the implementation of `awgn()`, it does use `randn()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%  create complex white normal noise 
noise = randn(size(Signal)) + 1i*randn(size(Signal));
% calculate the gain for the noise
noiseGain = rms(Signal)./rms(noise)*exp(-SNR(i)*log(10)/20);
% add it
SignalN = Signal + noiseGain*noise;
```

Comment: Thank you Hilmar.  I was not aware of the noise gain formula.  Could you please correct the logarithmic function in the second line.. the brackets are missing.

Comment: Done. Should have been $log(10)$. It's just turning dB into a linear gain